# div pushed to the right in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, html

On this page, there is a form at the bottom. In Internet explorer, the text in the form is pushed to the right, by the arrow it seems.

I tried to eliminate this, but no luck. Could someone help me out, please? Thank you!

Kind regards,
Stefaan

Comment: can you post some of your code

Comment: the div is pushed to right even in FF

Comment: Sorry, just saw the question has been put on hold. But it has been resolved already, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `clear: both;` to `.frm_forms.with_frm_style`

Comment: Thank you, this was my solution!